# Parameter count mismatch SQLTE

Tags: database, qt

Fairly newbie here to this and need some help, trying to save new employee information into my sqlite database from a user management screen in my application. I am throwing a Parameter count mismatch when I try to save new employee data into my sqlite employeeinfo database.

columns in my sqlite database table are as follows; Registration,Name,Surname,Access,Phone,Email,Username,Password

I am using the following code on pushbutton clicked;

```
void oviewsettings::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QString Registration, Name, Surname, Access, Phone, Email, Username, Password;
Registration=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Registration->text();
Name=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Name->text();
Surname=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Surname->text();
Access=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Access->text();
Phone=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Phone->text();
Email=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Email->text();
Username=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Username->text();
Password=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Password->text();


OViewMain conn;
if(!conn.connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Failed to open the database";
    return;
}
conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO employeeinfo(Registration,Name,Surname,Access,Phone,Email,Username,Password) VALUES ('"+Registration+"','"+Name+"','"+Surname+"','"+Access+"','"+Phone+"','"+Email+"','"+Username+"','"+Password+"')");
qry.addBindValue(":Registration");
qry.addBindValue(":Name");
qry.addBindValue(":Surname");
qry.addBindValue(":Access");
qry.addBindValue(":Phone");
qry.addBindValue(":Email");
qry.addBindValue(":Username");
qry.addBindValue(":Password");
qry.exec();

if(qry.exec())
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Save"),tr("Database Updated, Saved"));
    conn.connClose();
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
}

}
```

Comment: I think you need to have the placeholders in the query, then pass the value as the second parameter of `addBindValue`.

Comment: Are you able to break that down further for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the above, that makes total sense now you have broken it down.

Your updated code is on the money just with a small typo the bindValue has a capital B in your code and QT is case sensitive. so have retyped it below for anyone else having this issue to see it.

One further note: Although with the updated code it saves the user into the sql database, it throws a new error: UNIQUE constraint failed: employeeinfo.Registration Unable to fetch row.

But it does save the user into the DB. I would suppose I have to create a new question to why it throws this error, but would love it if someone could answer that to complete this thread.

See updated code here:

```
    QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO employeeinfo(Registration, Name, Surname, Access, Phone, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:Registration, :Name, :Surname, :Access, :Phone, :Email, :Username, :Password)");
    qry.bindValue(":Registration", Registration);
    qry.bindValue(":Name", Name);
    qry.bindValue(":Surname", Surname);
    qry.bindValue(":Access", Access);
    qry.bindValue(":Phone", Phone);
    qry.bindValue(":Email", Email);
    qry.bindValue(":Username", Username);
    qry.bindValue(":Password", Password);
    qry.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with qt but from using other prepared statements and looking at the manual it seems like it should be the following code.

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO employeeinfo(Registration, Name, Surname, Access, Phone, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:Registration, :Name, :Surname, :Access, :Phone, :Email, :Username, :Password)");
qry.BindValue(":Registration", Registration);
qry.BindValue(":Name", Name);
qry.BindValue(":Surname", Surname);
qry.BindValue(":Access", Access);
qry.BindValue(":Phone", Phone);
qry.BindValue(":Email", Email);
qry.BindValue(":Username", Username);
qry.BindValue(":Password", Password);
qry.exec();
```

The placeholders need to be in the query so the driver knowns where to write the values. The binding then needs a mapping to the placeholder and the value it should have. Additionally `BindValue()` uses named placeholders, `addBindValue()` uses anonymous/unnamed placeholders, here's an example using the latter.

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO employeeinfo(Registration, Name, Surname, Access, Phone, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
qry.addBindValue(Registration);
qry.addBindValue(Name);
qry.addBindValue(Surname);
qry.addBindValue(Access);
qry.addBindValue(Phone);
qry.addBindValue(Email);
qry.addBindValue(Username);
qry.addBindValue(Password);
qry.exec();
```